# Remove NA row from a single dataframe within list

Tags: r, dplyr

Remove NA row from a single dataframe within list

I'd like to do this within a pipe

```
#Sample data:
l <- list(a=c("X", "Y", "Z"),
     b = data.frame(a=c("A", "B", "C", NA), b=c("R", "G", "B", NA)),
     c = data.frame(header=c(1,2,3), value=c(0, 10, 15)))
```

#What I want:

```
> l
$a
[1] "X" "Y" "Z"

$b
  a b
1 A R
2 B G
3 C B

$c
  header value
1      1     0
2      2    10
3      3    15

## Failed attempt
list %>%
filter(purrr::map_df(b, ~!is.na(.)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specifically want to act on the list member named "b" you could use `map_if`:

```
l %>% 
  map_if(names(.) == "b", na.omit)
```

`lapply(l, na.omit)` will remove NA rows from any element of the list.

```
lapply(l, na.omit)

$a
[1] "X" "Y" "Z"

$b
  a b
1 A R
2 B G
3 C B

$c
  header value
1      1     0
2      2    10
3      3    15
```

If you really want to use `map` and pipes for any element:

```
l %>% 
  map(., na.omit)
```

Comment: ah map_if is what i wanted. Thanks!

Comment: What if i also wanted to filter out rows in c where header == 2. This doesn't work:  map_if(names(.) == "c", filter(header != "2"))

Comment: That's a little more involved: `l %>% map_if(names(.) ==  "c", ~filter(.x, header != 2))`

Comment: Thanks @neilfws. You are a wizard

Answer (score 0):

Filter() doesn't have a list method (thus the error: "Error in UseMethod("filter_") :    no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "list"")

You can put lapply on a pipe like this.

`l %>%  lapply(na.omit)`

a non-pipe way is

`l$b<-l$b[complete.cases(l$b),]`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `NA` if element in the list is a dataframe.

```
lapply(l, function(x) if(inherits(x, 'data.frame')) na.omit(x) else x)
```

and same with `map` :

```
purrr::map(l, ~if(inherits(.x, 'data.frame')) na.omit(.x) else .x)
```